# Jqplot functions is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Have below html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>

<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\hana\plugins\jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\hana\plugins\jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\hana\plugins\jquery.jqplot.css" /> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\hana\plugins\jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\hana\plugins\jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\hana\plugins\jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role = "page" id="chart_page">

  <script src = "http://X.X.X.X:8080/hana/show.js"></script>

<div data-role= "header"><h1>Opportunity Graph</h1></div>

<a data-role="button" id="barchart" data-inline="true">Bar Graph</a>

   <div id="chartdiv1" style="height:400px;width:300px;"></div>

</div> <!-- Page end -->


</body>

</html>
```

and simple show.js file on click event as

```
$.jqplot('chartdiv1',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
```

but I am getting error as
**Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'jqplot'**

can you please help me to resolve this I also tried to check first code at this [link](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php) but it is also giving error as "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BarRenderer' of undefined**"

help!!!

Comment: I am tring my code on Google Chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your scripts locations...

Paths like "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\" won't work on html page. Your scripts are maybe in "C:..." but your apache server does not recognise it. Try with relative url like "/hana\plugins\jquery.min.js".

Read this for more informations : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: Hi I Even tried with src="http://IPaddress:8080/hana/plugins/jquery.min.js" when I put this URL in browser I can see the file.

Comment: Please check with firebug or something equivalent if your scripts are loaded correctly. Try also to add http:// before js file path

Comment: sorry Jisay, I mean by adding http:// only .. for all scripts.. but still no luck.. I checked by giving relative path like ../plugins/  but not working..